# Strange build issue after upgrading to XCode 12

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode12

After updating XCode and running our project we're seeing a strange Objective C + Swift bridging issue which is outlined in the screenshot. Any ideas on what to try will be extremely helpful.

[image]

Comment: In released Xcode 12 I got a bridging issue with OSLog. Replaced 'import OSLog' with 'import os.log'.

Comment: Since Xcode12 is a bit buggy, this might not work, but you can try adding `arm64` to the `excluded architecture` field in the `build settings` and check (in Xcode 12GM).